# Download pdf from url using html

Tags: html, reactjs, pdf

```
    <a
        href={`https://storage.yandexcloud.net/statrix-static/incomes.pdf`}
        download
    >
        Скачать описание к отчёту
    </a>
```

Above code i am using to download pdf from URL.
But when i click it is opening the pdf url in browser instead of downloading.

Is there any to download pdf from link using React.js

Answer (score 1):

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = url;
link.download = 'file.pdf';
link.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'));
```

Comment: Please explain what this code does and how it does it.

Comment: So you can use this code inside a function, add the click event handler to the a tag which will call this function.
Give whatever name you want to give to the file.
This should let you download the file for you.